# Exporting data to .BRW format

Tags: php

I am developing an application that requires the output to be in .BRW format. I have already searched on Google which says that it is a file used by financial institution(s) mainly Calyx Point. Can anyone suggest me how to export data to .BRW format in PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

1. The old fashioned way - figure out the file format and write the file yourself.
2. OR get an application that supports BRW. Check if you can call that application through PHP and make it save the file for you.

Comment: how can php call a application could you explain?